# Are there ESlint rules for Vuex modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, eslint

In my application's codebase, there are many Vuex getters which return functions, similar to the following:

```js
const getters = {
  getStateScopedToApp: (state, getters) => appId => {
    // ... do stuff with appId
    return state.foo[appId];
  }
};
```

This was originally done because `appId` here comes from route parameters which are only available in components, and because due to the way data is loaded for the application, returning an object keyed by `appId` would either result in some values being incorrect or missing.

I have since found that this is an antipattern - getters which return functions close over the entire state and are thus updated any time `state` changes at all, effectively ruining Vuex's caching on the results of computed properties. What I was wondering is if there are any standard ESLint rules for Vuex modules that I could leverage to find and warn on patterns like this, to make them easier to track down and remove in favor of more cache-friendly getters. I couldn't find any on Google.

Comment: There are are framework things like eslint-plugin-react-hooks that address very common mistakes, but a linter cannot protect you against every way you can use a footgun. I didn't see this antipattern before and it doesn't seem common at all, but yes, it smells, this is the case for an action, not computed. Looks just like a good lesson to learn.